# React: export const + export default vs export default

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I've come across current component creation with "double" export. Can you please explain if there is a real use of it, or it's just author preference?

```
import React from 'react'
import DuckImage from '../assets/Duck.jpg'
import './HomeView.scss'

export const HomeView = () => (
  <div>
    <h4>Welcome!</h4>
    <img
      alt='This is a duck, because Redux!'
      className='duck'
      src={DuckImage} />
  </div>
)

export default HomeView
```

P.S: Current code is later bundled by webpack2.

Comment: They export it as a regular const and as the default const, so you can import it either with `import HomeView from "file"` or `import { HomeView } from "file"`.

Comment: export default allows stuff like `import React from 'react'`. export without default requires `{}` e.g. `import {React} from 'react'`. You can only have 1 default per file

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In this case, the two exports are exporting the same thing. 
Both

```
import Homeview
```

And

```
import { Homeview }
```

Will give you the same module (the HomeView component).

I see you're using Redux, though. *If* you were doing something like

```
export const HomeView ...

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeView);
```

That could be useful in that you might want to use the non-Redux-connected component sometimes, or you might need it for testing.

Comment: That last bit is a good point. Not just Redux, but if you want to add React's `PropTypes` to a function too.